# Standby controlfile error

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I am doing dataguard. I have manually done a backup for the standby database. It was working fine. Problem arose when I used the standby controlfile. On the primary, I have created a standby controlfile and transferred it to the standby.

```
scp test_sdy oracle@db3.oracle.com:/u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1/control01.ctl
cp /u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1/control01.ctl \
   /u03/app/oracle/flash_recover_area/TEST1/control02.ctl
```

The standby's `init.ora` contains:

```
*.control_files='/u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1/control01.ctl','/u03/app/oracle/flash_recovery_area/TEST1/control02.ctl'
```

When I start up the standby database using pfile, I get this error:

```
ORA-10458: standby database requires recovery
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 1 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1_SDY/system01.dbf'
```

Did I do something wrong with the standby control file? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does that file exist on your standby?

Comment: @mat:thanks for replying.no the file doesn't exit.

Comment: What is the path to system01.dbf on your primary, and is it the same as on the standby?

Comment: path is same for both primary and standby /u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1/system01.dbf

Comment: Data Guard is unidirectional. You can't simply open your standby for read/write like that, and there is no need to unless you actually want to do a fail-over and effectively make it your new production database.

Comment: Check out http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/data-guard-setup-11gr2.php for simple step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is in the parameters file of standby database, may be you have defined something as:

LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT='/u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1','/u03/app/oracle/oradata/TEST1_SDY'

This parameter change the location on dbfiles for standby version. Here a link of documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams112.htm#REFRN10098

If you remove this line in parameter file of standby database and restart should be work, with the same control file standby version created before.